# Image thumbnail styles are not created

Tags: media

I'm moving a website in a production server and it appears that the image thumbnails aren't created from an Image Field in a content.

The images are uploaded correctly but no files are created in styles folder. I've already set to 0777 each folder in case of a permission problem, but it's not that.

The big problem is that I can't remove the images, probably because it raises a forbidden file as it doesn't exist. The only error log I can find is an access denied but nothing else.

Does anybody has the same problem ?

It works okay on local... maybe an Apache issue to look at ?

[image]

Comment: maybe because you have the wrong user as the folder owner. If you're using ubuntu, inside your Drupal folder try `sudo chown www-data -R sites`

Comment: yes it appears that there was a permission folder problem. I couldn't use sudo as it is on a hosted server but by reinstalling totally drupal it looks okay

Comment: I managed to solve it using this: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/230392/73476

Answer (score 11):

**Solution for Drupal 8 that worked for me**:

- create sites/default/files/styles folder manually
- set its permissions to 775
- create .htaccess file in this folder with following content:

```
<Files *>
  SetHandler none
</Files>
```

Comment: i added files folder and every folder inside it 775 permission and now works(didn't had to modify .htaccess). Thank you!

Comment: Simply adding `.htaccess` worked for me.  The bigger question is, why is this necessary?  
`sites/default/styles` already existed with `775` perms, and Drupal had already been creating files on the server right and left.

Comment: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/289378/6884 answered it

Answer (score 5):

Having the same problem with a brand new Ubuntu 19.10 installation on development laptop.

As suggested in https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/224999/97472, adding

```
<Files *>
  SetHandler none
</Files>
```

is fixing a problem, image style generation works fine. However, this is not an optimal solution. Finally, figured out that i forgot to add apache mod-rewrite module. Executing next lines in console fixed the problem fully, no need for .htaccess manual fix:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
systemctl restart apache2
```

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes this is related to an odd space in one of your module or PHP files before the opening PHP tag... for example:

```
_
<?php

/**
 * Stuff here.
 */
```

That little line where the underscore is present can cause thumbnails to break on first render. See: [Image styles not generated on first page load until page refreshed](https://www.drupal.org/node/2195311) on Drupal.org.

To see if this might be your issue, grep your entire codebase for any files that have a newline, then a `<?php` tag. In my case, I found that the contrib Block Styles module had a submodule with a newline before the opening tag, and that caused a fair amount of grief!

Answer (score 1):

From settings.php Drupal 8, please try add following:

```
$config['image.settings']['suppress_itok_output'] = TRUE;
$config['image.settings']['allow_insecure_derivatives'] = TRUE;
```

suppress_itok_output = True for remove itok token from image.

Comment: This works but opens up the site for possible DDoS attacks.

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/forum/newsletters/security-advisories-for-drupal-core/2013-02-20/sa-core-2013-002-drupal-core-denial

Comment: This is security vulnerability?

Comment: "Posted by Drupal Security Team on 20 Feb 2013 at 20:50 UTC
Advisory ID: DRUPAL-SA-CORE-2013-002
Project: Drupal core
Version: 7.x
Date: 2013-February-20
Security risk: Critical
Exploitable from: Remote
Vulnerability: Denial of service
Description
Drupal core's Image module allows for the on-demand generation of image derivatives. This capability can be abused by requesting a large number of new derivatives which can fill up the server disk space, and which can cause a very high CPU load. Either of these effects may lead to the site becoming unavailable or unresponsive."

Answer (score 1):

I used this snippet code which forces drupal to create image style for an image :

```
$styles = ImageStyle::loadMultiple();
$image_uri = $entity->getFileUri();
/** @var \Drupal\image\Entity\ImageStyle $style */
foreach ($styles as $style) {
  $destination = $style->buildUri($image_uri);
  $style->createDerivative($image_uri, $destination);
}
```

this code can be used in a function iterating on a group of nodes, select their image and create styles for them or could be [used as file upload hook](https://www.flocondetoile.fr/blog/generate-programmatically-image-styles-drupal-8) so any time an image is uploaded the styles would be created manually.

Answer (score 0):

Drupal 8 solution for drupal image styles not generating:

set the permissions to 775 to sites/default/files/ folder. 
command [ $ sudo chmod 775 /var/www/html/drupal-8.7.6/sites/default/files/]

Comment the "SetHandler Drupal_Security_Do_Not_Remove_See_SA_2013_003" line in files folder .htaccess file.

Add the following lines in .htaccess file.

# Override the handler again if we're run later in the evaluation list.
  #SetHandler Drupal_Security_Do_Not_Remove_See_SA_2013_003
  SetHandler none

Answer (score 0):

Having tried multiple owner change commands and permissions did not work. 
The solution was simply :

sudo a2enmod rewrite

systemctl restart apache2