# Image styles do not work

Tags: media

I am struggling to find a solution for image styles not getting generated. The original pictures get uploaded to the server but no styles or thumbnails are generated.

I have checked folder permission and set it to 775 and even 777 (temporarily) for the /styles/ and its subfolders.

I even set `$conf['image_allow_insecure_derivatives']` to `TRUE`.

Yet I still get access denied for the anonymous users (not verified when I upload images and no styles or thumbnails).

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

Drupal version 8.5.3 Local dev with Aquia Dev Desktop.

I've tried all combinations with `.htaccess` (root, in `/files` and in `styles`) with no success.

Also tried with:

```
$config['image.settings']['suppress_itok_output'] = TRUE;
$config['image.settings']['allow_insecure_derivatives'] = TRUE;
```

No results.

Even though I had a `settings.local.php` **solution** was to uncommment this line in `settings.php`:

```
$settings['file_public_path'] = 'sites/default/files';
```

Answer (score 4):

I also had problems with image styles not generating and it turns out it was because mod_rewrite wasn't enabled in my apache2. Hope it helps someone

Comment: is right one of the main reasons image styles generation fails because of apache mod_rewrite is disabled

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me

added these lines in `settings.php`

```
$settings['file_public_path'] = 'sites/default/files';
$config['image.settings']['suppress_itok_output'] = TRUE;
$config['image.settings']['allow_insecure_derivatives'] = TRUE;
```

Answer (score 3):

By adding this line in setting.php this problem will be resolved and image will appear.

```
$config['image.settings']['allow_insecure_derivatives'] = TRUE;
```

Answer (score 2):

I have spent more than 48 hours looking for a solution for a Drupal 8 site and I have finally **SOLVED** it. 
I have tried any possible nginx config suggested everywhere, including [this](https://www.drupal.org/node/1109312#comment-11945228) and the one found [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/2150483#comment-11686279). Also checked any possible permissions issues on files and folders on the whole project to no avail...

What I found is that when uploading an image the system never got to write it to the image style folder... I discovered this when I created a new image style I realised the folders for that image style created correctly and the demo image was placed correctly as well.

Hinted by another user I turned my efforts to the temporary folder which drupal passes images through to generate image styles. I found that I have accidentally set a temporary folder within drupal filesystem, the setting was: `temp` in *Configuration > File system > Temporary directory*. This folder probably had wrong permissions and maybe it was the linux t permission also known as sticky bit that drupal needed for this. 
When I changed the temp folder location to `/tmp` (I'm on centos) image styles worked like a charm again immediately!!

Hope this helps someone...

---

### Update

I run into this problem again, but the solution was a bit different. If the above does not work for you and you use nginx, make sure you have the correct nginx directives which can be found here: 
https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/recipes/drupal/

Answer (score 1):

I've tried this /tmp folder trick and it didn't work for me; what did though is this:
In .htaccess file in /sites/default/files folder i've changed this:

```
Options -Indexes -ExecCGI -Includes -MultiViews
```

to this

```
#Options -Indexes -ExecCGI -Includes -MultiViews
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
```

Have no idea if it has a security issue or anything else, since i'm total zero in this things, but it worked :)
Well, I also have all the folders in /sites/default/files 775'd, including files itself.

**UPDATE #1!**
Actually, only commenting the first line like this

```
#Options -Indexes -ExecCGI -Includes -MultiViews
```

works for me, so one of those options standing on our way to image styles. I don't know exactly which one, please feel free to play with them.

**UPDATE #2!**
Actually, the update #1 works only in conjunction with the following setting in the hosting panel for my domain:

```
Use Apache instead Nginx for handling the static files like .jpg .gif .js .css .rar .exe .mp3 etc.
```

Yes, I have this setting in the hosting panel.

So, seems like it's final - the two things - ***commenting Options in the .htaccess and use Apache instead of Nginx***

Answer (score 1):

As for me, the issue with broken thumbnails was fixed
in nginx config

when I added "location" directive below

```
location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico|svg)$
{
    try_files $uri @rewrite;
    expires max;
    log_not_found off;
}
```

and restarted server, it was never appeared

( using drupal 8.6.13 )

permissions of `sites/default/files/styles` are 777 for nginx user 
(owner of it)