# Some image styles not generating while other are

Tags: media

I'm seeing a strange issue where some of our image styles seem to be broken while others work fine. The broken ones are showing the typical signs of the source image existing while the image style url used on the page is broken. I can't seem to find any consistencies -- similar effects are used on working and broken styles, and some broken ones are defaults (thumbnail) while others are customized. Quite odd.

Any ideas what might cause this? Site is running D9. I'm hesitant to purge the image styles in case it doesn't work and we end up with even more broken images.

Comment: You can use `drush image:flush` to selectively purge the broken styles and see if that helps: https://drushcommands.com/drush-9x/image/image:flush/  That way at least you won't be making the problem worse than it already is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution ended up being needing to enable mod_rewrite as described in [Image styles do not work](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/217689/image-styles-do-not-work). No idea why some images were generating fine while others weren't, as it seems like all should be affected equally but, in either case, the issue was resolved all around by enabling mod_rewrite.