# image styles not being created

Tags: 9

I've got a production site running 9.4.6 in which each user profile includes an image, and the image has to appear as both a thumbnail and as max325 image styles at various points. These image styles are not being created. I carefully followed all suggestions [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/217689/image-styles-do-not-work) without luck. You can see the problem [here](https://nolapoetry.com/user/75) if that's helpful.

Comment: Do you see any log messages?

Comment: No, nothing in the Drupal or server logs.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Image styles do not work](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/217689/image-styles-do-not-work)

Comment: Above is an automatic comment. I marked this a likely duplicate as there is no new information in this question.

Comment: No, I meticulously followed all the suggestions there without success. Sorry, this is my first question and I don't know the protocol -- should I have left a comment there, instead?

Comment: Is it only the User's images or all images style are not being generated? I would remove the added entries in settings.php : `suppress_itok_output` and `allow_insecure_derivatives` (but keep `file_public_path`) coming from the suggestions you have followed then clear the cache.

Comment: No image styles are being generated. I removed suppress_itok_output and allow_insecure_derivatives, kept file_public_path, and cleared the cache -- no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my web host had nginx installed. It wasn't in their help files and I wasn't aware. As soon as that was removed, the image styles created smoothly. Thanks for all your comments!